# How can improve this picture in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, digital

I took a picture of this toy, cut it out of its background, put it in a new document in front of white background and added some shadow. My real intention was to make a **SIMPLE**(white bg) bunny wallpaper. Something doesn’t seem quiet right with this picture tho. How can I improve it to make it look like a real wallpaper?
[image]

Comment: This question can be migrated to GD.SE with the [critique] tag if necessary.

Comment: You may want to ask this on photography.se as the issue is really about how the photo was originally taken. Looks like it was taken with a harsh lighting source. You want an indirect, soft lighting source to evenly light the entire object if the goal is to have it appear solo in a vast white expanse. If done correctly, you shouldn't even need to edit it much in photoshop. Using a light-box would be ideal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyxzC5kqbyw

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you mean by "make it look like a real wallpaper." In any event, I see 2 issues with the image:

1. The bunny is overexposed and that's causing the highlights to be blown out. If you shot it RAW then you could decrease the exposure a bit to fix that. (You might then need to compensate by raising the mids.)
2. The shadow doesn't match the lighting. The bunny is lit from the right side, but the shadow is drawn as if it was lit from above.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I improve it to make it look like a real wallpaper?

You can't.

The highlights are blown.  That means information has been irreversibly lost.
If you still have the raw file, then *maybe* the highlight information is in there and can be retrieved.

Otherwise, go back and take the picture again, this time exposing properly.